# Select Multiple Images in Android

Tags: android

I want to **Select Multiple**  **Images** in **Android**.

I write following code through which I can select only one image.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK);
```

How I can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know standard Intent doesn't support multiple selection.
You could try to extend ListView and make your own custom view to allow multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)//Api Level 18
public void selectPhotos(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "select Multiple Images"), SELECT_PHOTOS_RESULT);
}
```